# How does ruby tell the difference between instance method and class method definition?

Tags: ruby

In normal ruby code, I can normally omit `self`:

```
class User
  def greeting
    # these 2 are the same:
    puts "Hi, #{name}"
    puts "Hi, #{self.name}"
  end
end
```

but why are these 2 different:

```
# 1
class User
  def self.greeting
    # ...
  end
end

# 2
class User
  def greeting
    # ...
  end
end
```

Why can't I just omit the `self`? What's the difference here to ruby code compiler's perspective?

I know #1 is class method definition (Singleton method definition) and #2 is instance method definition. But how did ruby work with context and self to arrive at this difference in method definition?

Comment: your question is not clear. How is #1 different from #2? they are not.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove self in #2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a **method body**, `self` refers to the **receiver**. In lines 3..4 of the following, once the receiver is determined to be a `User` instance (by the `def greeting` syntax), `self` refers to that instance.

```
class User
  def greeting
    puts "Hi, #{name}"      # method body
    puts "Hi, #{self.name}" # method body
  end
end
```

In a **class body**, `self` refers to the **class**. In lines 2, 4, 8, 10 of the following, the class is `User`, so `def self.greeting` is the same as `def User.greeting`.

```
class User
  def self.greeting # class body
    # ...
  end               # class body
end

class User
  def greeting      # class body
    # ...
  end               # class body
end
```

---

But I actually think your real issue is not what `self` means, but rather what "an omitted receiver" means, in different contexts.

In method-**calling** syntax, an omitted receiver stands for `self`. So the following two are the same:

```
name
self.name
```

In method-**defining** syntax, an omitted receiver stands for "any instance of the class". So the following two are not the same:

```
def User.greeting; ... end
def greeting; ... end
```

When you define an instance method, there is no explicit way to express "any instance of the class", so actually omission is mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

The `self` is sometimes needed (otherwise it wouldn't exist at all). The first example you give is a case where it is redundant. Both of those method calls refer to the same method.

There are times when it *is* needed to distinguish between two different behaviours.

In your examples #1 and #2 the `self` is used to make sure the method is defined on the class, rather than being on instances of the class. The `self` isn't redundant in this case. This is the way that the Ruby interpreter knows where you want the method defined. It might be helpful to think about the `self` in your very first example as a different thing to the `self` in examples #1 and #2. It might be helpful to think of the `self` in #1 and #2 as "`class`"? They're the same keyword but how they are used is not directly interchangeable.

Another example of where it isn't redundant:

```
# user.rb

def method1
  name = "Henry" # Sets a local variable called `name`
end

def method2
  self.name = "Henry" # Sets the user's `name` attribute
end
```

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your other comments and change in title. Specifically this part:  It might be helpful to think about the `self` in your very first example as a different thing to the `self` in examples #1 and #2. It might be helpful to think of the `self` in #1 and #2 as `class`? They're the same word but what they are used for and change is not directly interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Methods defined on a class are *instance methods*:

```
class Animal
  def dog
    "woof"
  end

  def cat
    "meow"
  end
end
```

They are so-named because they respond to any instance of the class, meaning that their receiver must be an instance of the class:

```
Animal.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:dog, :cat] 
animal = Animal.new
  #=> #<Animal:0x00005bfb0c55ae98>  
animal.dog
  #=> "woof"
Animal.dog
  #=> NoMethodError (undefined method `dog' for Animal:Class)
```

To define a method whose receiver is a class (a *class method*) we define the method on the class's singleton class. For the class `Animal` we could write either of the following.

```
class Animal
  class << Animal
    def pig(n)
      "#{n} little pigs"
    end
  end
end

Animal.methods(false)
  #=> [:pig] 
Animal.pig(3)
  #=> "3 little pigs"
```

or

```
Animal.define_singleton_method(:pig) do |n|
  "#{n} little pigs"
end

Animal.methods(false)
  #=> [:pig] 
Animal.pig(3)
  #=> "3 little pigs"
```

The line `class < Animal`<sup>1</sup> changes the scope to `Animal`'s singleton class, causing the value of `self` to change to that class as well.

So what does this have to do with the question, that is, defining methods `def self.my_method ...`? The short answer is that there is no need to define methods in that way. Please be patient--I'll get to that.

Note that the method `pig`, defined on `Animal`'s singleton class, is inherited by the singleton class of subclasses of `Animal`:

```
class Swine < Animal
end

Swine.instance_methods & [:dog, :cat]
  #=> [:dog, :cat]
Swine.methods & [:pig]
  #=> [:pig]
```

We can also define methods on many *unique objects*. Consider `animal`, an instance of `Animal`:

```
animal.define_singleton_method(:rodent) do |n|
  "I'm rodent ##{n}"
end

animal.rodent(3241)
  #=> "I'm rodent #3241"
```

`animal` is the only receiver to which this method will respond:

```
Animal.new.rodent(55)
  #=> #NoMethodError (undefined method `rodent' for
  #     #<Animal:0x00005bfb0c530670>)
```

In fact, we can define methods on every object that has a singleton class, which is most objects:

```
str = "cow"
str.define_singleton_method(:greeting) { "moo" }
str.greeting
  #=> "moo"

arr = [1,2]
arr.define_singleton_method(:greeting) { "I'm an array" }
arr.greeting
  #=> "I'm an array"

module M; end
M.define_singleton_method(:greeting) { "I'm a module" }
M.greeting
  #=> "I'm a module"

piggy = Animal.method(:pig)
  #=> #<Method: Animal.pig> 
piggy.define_singleton_method(:greeting) { 
  "I'm a singleton method" }
piggy.greeting
  #=> "I'm a singleton method"
```

We can do this with all Ruby objects that have a singleton class. That comprises all objects except those having *immediate values* (objects passed by value), which include `nil`, `true`, `false`, Integers, Symbols, and some Floats. In addition, objects that have been frozen (e.g., `"Hi".freeze`) do not have a singleton class.

Suppose now we write

```
class Animal
  def Animal.pig(n)
    "#{n} little pigs"
  end
end
```

or (same thing)

```
class Animal
  def self.pig(n)
    "#{n} little pigs"
  end
end
```

(We're finally there!)

What is this new way of defining a method? It is in fact just a shorthand way of defining a method on `Animal`'s singleton class. Think of it as merely [syntactic sugar](https://medium.com/@Parmaviolet/trick-or-treat-ruby-s-syntactic-sugar-80c9d80a4c4b). Just as writing `2 + 2` instructs Ruby to execute `2.+(2)`, `Animal.` or `self.` in the first line of the method definition merely instructs Ruby to execute the following.

```
class Animal
  class << self
    def pig(n)
      "#{n} little pigs"
    end
  end
end
```

In other words, the creation of class method by writing `def Animal.my_method...` or `def self.my_method...` is not needed at all; it is there merely as a convenience for Ruby coders.

<sup>1 That line would generally be written `class << self`, which is acceptable as `self` equals `Animal` when the line is executed. Using `<< self` is merely a convenience should the class be renamed.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In a class if you define a method on self, it defines it on the class. E.g.

```
class User
  def self.greeting
    "Hello User"
  end
end
```

Then you can call

```
User.greeting
# => "Hello User"
```

If you define a method without self, then that method is defined for objects of that class. E.g.:

```
class User
  def greeting
    "Hello user"
  end
end
```

Then you have to create a new user object to call `greeting`.

```
user = User.new
user.greeting
# => "Hello user"
```

Comment: I know this but I don't know why it work like this. I would like to understand how ruby handles context and self and arrive at this difference

Answer (score 0):

`self` is mandatory while defining class methods whereas without self keyword it will be treated as instance methods. `class << self; end;` block also used to define numbers of class methods.

These methods are loaded when your class is loaded and above will help to distinguish them.

It will be simply like relating with **real life example**.

You have number of accounts having authentication provided on your computer, valid person with right password can enter inside account. Once you enter inside account, you do not need to mention who you are! It always count you the one who entered.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is important to understand that there is no such thing as *class method* or a *singleton method* in Ruby. There is only exactly one kind of methods: instance methods.

The *real* question is: what *module* is the method defined in?

["Singleton method" and "class method" are simply shorthand names that we use for "method that is defined in the singleton class" and "method that is defined in the singleton class of an object whose class is `Class`".]

There are two forms of method definitions in Ruby:

```
def some_expression.some_name; end
```

and

```
def some_name; end
```

The first one will first evaluate the expression `some_expression` and then define a method named `some_name` inside the *singleton class* of the resulting object.

The second one will define a method named `some_name` in what is called the *default definee*. The default definee is *usually* the *closest lexically enclosing module definition*. For example, in this case:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    def foo
      def bar; end
    end
  end
end

include Foo::Bar

foo
# At this point, `bar` will be defined, but where?
```

Here, `bar` will be defined as an instance method of `Foo::Bar`, because `bar` is the closest lexically enclosing module definition. There is another lexical definition that is even closer, namely the method definition of `foo`, but that is not a module definition.

A little bit more puzzling:

```
Foo = Class.new do
  def foo; end
end
```

This will define `foo` as an instance method of `Foo`, even though *technically* this is not a module definition, it is "just" a block. However, that's why I wrote "usually" above: some methods can change the default definee, and `Class::new` is one of those methods (similar to how, e.g. `Object#instance_eval` changes the value of `self`).

Another example:

```
def foo; end
```

In this case, *there is no* lexically enclosing module definition. At the top-level, the default definee is `Object` but with a twist: the default visibility is also `private`.

All of this is explained in greater detail in the brilliant blog post [Three implicit contexts in Ruby](https://blog.yugui.jp/entry/846) by yugui.

Now, the only thing missing is: what does the expression `self` evaluate to inside a module definition? Well, you can test it out if you want:

```
class Foo
  p self
end
```

The answer is that inside a module definition, `self` evaluates to the module being defined. (Kind of makes sense, does it?)

Therefore, in

```
class Foo
  def self.foo; end
end
```

`foo` is defined in the singleton class of `Foo`.